# Gmail API to add multiple signatures

Tags: gmail-api

We are looking for an API to add multiple signatures on Gmail accounts. Is it available?
We integrate an API to update the current signature but we need to add multiple signatures now.

Comment: You need to use a [service account with domain-wide delegation](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/service-account#delegatingauthority) for that, and that requires being a domain admin. You can use [users.settings.sendAs.create](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/reference/rest/v1/users.settings.sendAs/create) for that. Does this answer your question?

Comment: I am using https: //www.googleapis.com/auth/admin.directory.userschema in scope using postman request but it says "ome requested scopes were invalid"

What scope should i send.

Comment: If you're using `sendAs.create`, you should provide scope `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.settings.sharing`.

Comment: I provided this scope and now I am getting "Invalid user id specified in request/Delegation denied".
I created a service account using an admin user.

Comment: Did you confer domain-wide delegation and are you impersonating an account?

Comment: yes I did confer domain-wide delegation

Comment: Are you impersonating an account? Consider providing the relevant parts of the code.

Comment: No , i am not impersonating an account.

Answer (score 0):

#### Issue:

You are not impersonating an account.

#### Explanation:

The whole point of granting domain-wide delegation to a service account is to be able to act on behalf of any user in the domain. If you don't impersonate another account in the domain, you are using the service account by itself, and the fact that you've granted domain-wide delegation doesn't have any effect (the service account by itself is not even part of the domain).

More specifically, you have to impersonate the account to which you want to add a signature, and use that to [create an alias](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/reference/rest/v1/users.settings.sendAs/create) with a signature or to [patch an existing one](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/reference/rest/v1/users.settings.sendAs/patch).

Not sure which language are you using, here you can see examples of impersonation in multiple languages: [Preparing to make an authorized API call](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/service-account#authorizingrequests).

#### Reference:

- [Delegating domain-wide authority to the service account](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/service-account#delegatingauthority)
- [Managing signatures](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/guides/alias_and_signature_settings#managing_signatures)

Comment: Thanks a lot, got it, now and it's working.